# Hindu scriptures and Christianity

Tags: scripture, other-religions, christianity, non-hindu

Now this question is controversial and keep in mind I am not a syncretist. However, to Hindu text mention any mysterious figure that possibly could resemble the figure of Christ? If not what about mysterious divine prophets in general?

Comment: The missionaries inserted Christ, Noah, Adam, etc. in some editions of the Bhaviṣya Purāṇa, and currently the editions we have, contain that nonsense.
Prophets aren't actually a thing in Hindu tradition tbh.

Comment: @Bingming No not really and if they did it would give us more credibility, because predicted the future. So, stop with these liberal lies please sir. True prophets aren't much of a thing but are comparable to Rishis. I just want to know in older text if such people are mysteriously mentioned.

Comment: These aren't some 'liberal' lies, you can ask the ācāṛyas. I don't really care what you may think and if your believe them or not. I am not a person who accepts the idea of 'interpolations' in śāstras. But the ones I have pointed are deliberate insertions by missionaries in Bhaviṣya Purāṇa, which is clear from the content. And they aren't mentioned in other śāstras. Also,  'prophets' aren't comparable to Ṛṣis. The one who has been speaking 'liberal' nonsense here, is you all along. 'Prophets' don't matter in Hindu tradition, nor are they mentioned. If you can't accept that, it's your problem.

Comment: Stop looking for validation of 'religions' such as Christianity, Islam, etc. in Hindu texts. If you really care so much about those 'religions', then consult their scriptures. And note that, only 'liberals' (the word you used) like you care. In my eyes, Christianity, etc. doesn't even stand as something. I don't care about it, but I don't want its nonsense forced upon Hindu tradition.

Comment: @Bingming, but I am not forcing nonsense if I was I wouldn't be asking the question this is just one out of curiosity, also while Christian missionaries did fabricate some scriptures it wasn't all. I am sorry I called you a liar, but interpolations came from within the tradition as well as externally ofc.

Comment: @Bingming I am distressed I cannot believe Brihaspati the one who cursed Budh for being born of evil lust did lust himself I am praying to Budh, but I adore Brihaspati still please clear this distress what should I do?

Comment: I have already explained, but you don't read the explanation properly, I can't help it.

Comment: @Haridasa if you don't like then reject as a prakshipt. Site is not for I don't like this part. I like that part. There are many prakshipts in many texts. But holy vedas are without any prakshipt.

Comment: @Hope you have seriously got me mixed up. What I aim to have for this question is any mysterious divine figures some of which could possibly have a few connections to Abrahamic figure, but rather the mysterious aspect itself if there is some unknown divinity.

Comment: @Haridasa I didn't say Christians added interpolations in all śāstras. I only mentioned in Bhaviṣya Purāṇa (and that too I only talked about Christian additions in it), and that is basically the only one. Rest are some nonsense fabricated texts like Allopaniṣat by others.  And I don't accept the colonial idea of interpolations from within the tradition, even though that's quite popular among 'educated' colonial and post-colonial Indians (who are influenced by Indology).

Comment: @Bingming I agree with your regards for many texts, but there is no proof of Bhavaishya Purana being interpolated by Christians.

Comment: @Bingming stop putting words in my mouth if to you curiosity is bad, then so be it. I was just stating facts that you have a problem accepting. I do not believe in the Bhavaishya Purana, but if you read it clearly isn't interpolated by missionaries unlike the very dubious Euzrovedam.

Comment: Facts such as 'Ṛṣis are equivalent to prophets'. These facts no proper Hindu can accept here. You want to accept or reject Christian additions is upto you, not me. I don't care what you choose to do really. I have already stated properly. If you want Abrahamic figures, stop looking for them in Hindu śāstras, for your search would be in vain. One śāstra which does mention, I have named.

Comment: @Bingming I said Rishis are comparable, but not equivlent to prophets why you keep on lying psuedo-hindu? Bro I already stated I don't want I am just curious and it doesn't even have to be an Abrahmic figure any mysterious figure would do. I guess your brain cells are pea sized for this level thought. Also I am concerned you're the one answering questions on this site with such a mentality.

Comment: Also the general term for prophet is someone who is like a messenger of faith lol other than god ofc.

Comment: Also I didn't claim anything lol why I am asking.

Comment: All you want to do is point the blame on missionaries for everything. Did they do bad absolutely that's why I asked for GOA primary sources as well as spread the fact that the Euzorvedam and Allopanishad are frauds. But, the Bhavashya Purana has no record of being written by missionaries and if they did they're idiots as it gives our faith more credance as we predicted the future and Christ I believe in that text is Shiva devotee. But I wanted to know if their was any other mysterious figures similair or alluding to abrahmic religious leader in either a positive or negetive light.

Comment: Based on older text and even if their is no connection I still want to know these mysterious figures. You just want to argue for the sake of arguing and present or rather distort the Vedic fiath without knowing a thing about it.

Comment: Until you show proof Bhavaishya Purana is interplorated by Christians don't speak.

Answer (score 2):

There are very fundamental differences between Hinduism and Christianity, so it is unlikely that authentic Hindu scriptures would talk about Jesus Christ.

One fundamental difference between Christianity and Hinduism is presented here.

In Christinanity, [Jesus died for the sins of humanity.](https://www.ihcc.org/Resources/Articles/christ-died-for-our-sins-according-to-the-scriptures)

> The first thing Jesus said regarding the ministry of the Holy Spirit was that He would convict the world of sin (John 16:8). As a result, we are able to recognize that we are sinners, and can in turn comprehend our need for Christ to die in our place to pay our penalty. **“He Himself bore our sins in His body on the tree” (1 Pet. 2:24). In short, He died for our sins.**

> Galatians 1:4: **The Lord Jesus Christ is the One “who gave Himself for our sins so that He might rescue us from this present evil age, according to the will of our God and Father.” He gave Himself for our sins; He paid the penalty and provided atonement.**

But, in **Bhagavad Gita**, Bhagavan Krishna says that God accepts neither our good deeds nor our bad deeds.

> nādattē kasyacitpāpaṅ na caiva sukṛtaṅ vibhuḥ.
> ajñānēnāvṛtaṅ jñānaṅ tēna muhyanti jantavaḥ৷৷5.15৷৷

> **The Omnipresent (Vibhu) neither accepts anybody's sin nor even virtue.** Knowledge remains covered by ignorance. Thereby the creatures become deluded.

Commenting on this, Sri Adi Shankara says -

> 5.15 Vibhuh, the Omnipresent; na adatte, neither accepts; kasyacit, anybody's-**even a devotee's**; papam, sin; na ca eva, nor even; does He accept sukrtam, virtue offered by devotees

Thus, in Hinduism, one's good/bad karmas have to be enjoyed/suffered by oneself. OR, they can be destroyed by Knowledge of Brahman (excluding prArabdha karma).

> yasya sarvē samārambhāḥ kāmasaṅkalpavarjitāḥ.
> **jñānāgnidagdhakarmāṇaṅ** tamāhuḥ paṇḍitaṅ budhāḥ ৷৷Bhagavad Gita 4.19৷৷

> He whose undertakings are all devoid of desires and (selfish) purposes and **whose actions have been burnt by the fire of knowledge**, him the wise call a sage.

Thus, Ishwara will not take up anybody's sins.

Comment: This is a partial answer so I cannot fully accept it what about other mysterious beings mentioned in scripture doesn't have to be related to Abrahmic figures just in general context.

Comment: I love how you used the Bhagavad Gita however the best place for catalyzing divine knwoledge.